# Do any texts explicitly forbid Hindus from eating beef?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, food, non-vegetarian, cows

I have been told many a times that I shouldn't eat beef because I am a Hindu by religion. Even though I have *never worshiped a cow in my life* or interacted with any on more than exotic basis, I find it hard to understand the logic behind not eating beef.

My argument against this has been the same as many others who choose to do those things which may or may not be explicitly forbidden in Hinduism. For instance, the consumption of alcohol is a controversial subject in Hinduism.

As a country India does not sell beef so I haven't been exposed to it earlier, but traveling often increased my curiosity and now I tend to not mind eating it.

Are there any **specific logical or better arguments** or textual facts which suggest that eating beef is explicitly forbidden in Hinduism **except the idea of worshiping cows**?

Comment: Im a Hindu, but I had meat. When first time i was eating it I was feeling very upset from inside. And later after time passed i realized its cus i was raised to be so..

Comment: For every religion there is a holy animal. for example, christians have easter bunny (_I don't know what muslims have but I am sure there is one_). Like that hindus have cow.

Comment: @Mr_Green Christians don't eat bunnies? -_-

Comment: @AdityaSomani they eat everything I presume. but christians !== Hindus.. right?

Comment: @Mr_Green Indeed, but then the holy animal point is rendered invalid because as you mentioned Christianity has a holy animal but still eats it, which tells me that holy animal is not the reason we don't eat cows. Correlation not equal to causation.

Comment: @AdityaSomani `holy` means it is `sacred`. So, we Hindus should show respect towards sacredness. please stop comparing other religions with Hindu religion. I just meant to say in my first comment that every religion has a holy animal. if you want to eat a animal, eat it happily but that is not what Hinduism states.

Comment: @Mr_Green Sorry if I offended you, but my interest was not to debate my life choices. It was to debate why a religion says what it says. I'm not comparing two religions. Let's not create barriers within religions based on differences, let's bring them closer based on what's common. The world would be a better place. Cheers!

Comment: Cow is "gOmAta" equivalent to one's own mother and the Mother Goddess. Just as one wouldn't harm one's mother, one must not harm the cow, let alone eat it. Only when "gO" and "brAhmaNa" are well, does the society prosper according to Hindu belief.

Comment: The Easter bunny is not a holy animal in Christianity. It is a fun symbol for kids associated with Easter. It is not venerated, worshipped, or held sacred. Other animals, like the fish (a symbol of Christ), are just symbols or metaphors. Just as the swan or goose (hamsa) is a resonant symbol, the Easter bunny (representing a virgin birth) and the fish (representing Christ) are only metaphors. Judaism and Islam only have prohibitions against animals--they don't have holy animals.

Comment: To address exactly this question, I have written a detailed four-part article on the issue of Beef in Hinduism. You can go through them- Part 1- Hinduism and Cow- http://www.newsgram.com/beef-controversy-hinduism-and-cow/ Part 2- Yajna, Madhuparka, and the use of beef- http://www.newsgram.com/beef-controversy-yajna-madhuparka-and-the-use-of-beef/ Part 3- Origins of beef consumption in India- http://www.newsgram.com/beef-controversy-origins-of-beef-consumption-in-india/ Part 4- Beef parties and the celebration of violence- http://www.newsgram.com/beef-controversy-beef-parties-and-the-celebratio

Comment: We worship cow as "Mata", means if we eat beaf, that is equal to eating our mother.

Comment: Go seva is a fundamental tenet of Hinduism. Hence a Hindu does not eat beef

Comment: @user1195 I don't think gau seva is a fundamental tenet of Hinduism.

Comment: Manusmriti parva 11 speaks of a punishment for killing cows. However, parva 5 tells us that any meat can be eaten if the animal (even a cow) was killed as part of a sacrifice (bali) and offered to one as prasadam.

Comment: beef is gross. what more is needed? alcohol is gross too, but appears not gross

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Not just beef, eating any kind of meat is by default prohibited in Hinduism**. Consider the following statements from the primary Hindu book of law:

> 1. Meat can never be obtained without injury to living creatures, and
>      injury to sentient beings is detrimental to (the attainment of)
>      heavenly bliss; let him therefore shun (the use of) meat. [Manu
>      Smriti - 5.48]
> 2. Having well considered the (disgusting) origin of flesh and the
>      (cruelty of) fettering and slaying corporeal beings, let him
>      entirely abstain from eating flesh. [Manu Smriti - 5.49]
> 3. He who permits (the slaughter of an animal), he who cuts it up, he
>      who kills it, he who buys or sells (meat), he who cooks it, he who
>      serves it up, and he who eats it, (must all be considered as) the
>      slayers (of the animal). [Manu Smriti - 5.51]
> 4. There is no greater sinner than that (man) who, though not
>      worshipping the gods or the manes, seeks to increase (the bulk of)
>      his own flesh by the flesh of other (beings). [Manu Smriti - 5.52]
> 5. He who during a hundred years annually offers a horse-sacrifice, and
>      he who entirely abstains from meat, obtain the same reward for their
>      meritorious (conduct). [Manu Smriti - 5.53]
> 6. By subsisting on pure fruit and roots, and by eating food fit for
>      ascetics (in the forest), one does not gain (so great) a reward as
>      by entirely avoiding (the use of) flesh. [Manu Smriti - 5.54]

All these statements convey one and one fact only, abstaining from eating meat as it causes pain and suffering to other animals. Now consider the following two statements:

> 1. One may eat meat when it has been sprinkled with water, while
>      Mantras were recited, when Brahmanas desire (one's doing it), when
>      one is engaged (in the performance of a rite) according to the law,
>      and when one's life is in danger. [Manu Smriti - 5.27]
> 2. He who eats meat, when he honours the gods and manes, commits no
>      sin, whether he has bought it, or himself has killed (the animal),
>      or has received it as a present from others. [Manu Smriti - 5.32]

So this is the thing regarding Hinduism, there is no one strict law. Every thing depends upon the context and intention. Hinduism informs you what to do and not do, but it doesn't command you to do anything in particular. The system of Karma takes care of all. Do whatever you want to do, but be ready to reap the corresponding result. This is the doctrine of Hinduism.

> As many hairs as the slain beast has, so often indeed will he who    killed it without a (lawful) reason suffer a violent death in future
>   births. [Manu Smriti - 5.38]

Depending upon the context and intention, Hinduism even allows actions that are generally forbidden. So **the question you should ask yourself is whether you are eating beef out of rigid necessity**. Is there no other food available for you to eat? Are you eating it because it tastes good? Ask yourself such questions and then decide. Listen to what your heart says, not what logic says. If everyone is doing the wrong things, should you do them as well? Would you like to be killed and eaten by others if you were a cow or any other animal?

Comment: My brain forces me to contradict with some logic here. For instance, **"He who during a hundred years annually offers a horse-sacrifice, and he who entirely abstains from meat, obtain the same reward for their meritorious (conduct)."** Why is it okay to sacrifice horses but not eat horses?

Comment: Sacrifice of horses is meant not for the purpose of enjoying its meat. See the point no 4 [5.52]

Comment: But the animal still gets killed? What is the purpose behind killing the animal?

Comment: If you go into detail, then horse sacrifice is done for a yajnya known as Aswamedha. In sacrifices when the animal is killed it obtains a higher birth and also it's offered as food to some gods or goddesses, but not when its done for the purpose of eating. So even the action is the same, the intention and karma involved is different. Killing is just an action, it's intention that defines the nature of the action.

Comment: _"All these statements convey one and one fact only, abstaining from eating meat as it causes **pain** and suffering to other animals."_ Scientifically Animals can be killed without causing them any kind of pain, e.g. _Halal_ food --made of an animal's meat-- is obtained without causing any pain to the animal.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq00ZhrcU-I) says that in _Manu Smriti Ch.5-V.41_ it is written that eating those animals which are made to be eaten is not a sin. Is it correct?

Comment: How is it justified to kill cow in gomegh just because it is in presence of yagna , I mean there is no logic in doing that, if we worship cow  and call her a mother how is it logical or even okay to kill it in on other worship called gomegh yagna? Isn't it foolish illogical type of concept?

Comment: Also how is manusmriti 5 citation about not eating meat but killing a horse is good?

Comment: @Yogi, 'how killing a horse is justified?' (Manu Smriti - 5.53 ) was already asked in the very first comment above and I believe it was sufficiently addressed by BeHappy.

Comment: @sv. I am saying that killing innocent horse even for yagna is wrong.I have seen that comment before asking about ashwamedha

Comment: @Yogi Animal sacrifice in Vedic Yagnas is definitely justified, and pretty much all the commentators on Brahma Sutras are in universal agreement on this point; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8883/36

Comment: @Yogi, I believe BeHappy is no longer active on the forum to respond to you directly but he did make a point in his answer: _Depending upon the context and intention, Hinduism even allows actions that are generally forbidden._

Comment: This is Gold : `Would you like to be killed and eaten by others if you were a cow or any other animal?`

Comment: O pandit, dont spread lies about Hinduism.

Comment: @user16678 "Scientifically Animals can be killed without causing them any kind of pain, e.g. Halal food ... is obtained without causing any pain to the animal" the stupidest thing ever heard, worse than ramblings of old maulanas. Halal is one of cruelest ways of slaughtering an animal. Prove me wrong https://www.icv.org.au/about/about-islam-overview/what-is-halal-a-guide-for-non-muslims/

Comment: But if killing is prohibited in **Manu Smriti**, how is that Shiva ordered to kill the first being they see and bring the head to attach it to Ganesha

Comment: @Up-In-Air - Rules for men are not applicable to Gods. This has been stated several in places across our scriptures

Comment: @USer345738380 no it isn't Gold. Plants *do* have a life too.

Comment: @BeHappy your comment *So even the action is the same, the intention and karma involved is different* contradicts whatever you've written in your answer about Hinduism. Plants also have life. But our intention to "eat" plants is not cruel right? So how come someone eating meat be "wrong" if they are eating for survival? I'm sorry but I find that this concept in Hinduism needs to be verified. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Vikas but we don't cut plants with roots. We eat only their products like vegetables and fruits.... We don't kill plants.....

Comment: @USer345738380 carrots, potatos? Further, egg plant could be fruit but it contains seeds, which are like the plants children and we are actually killing them. This is just example. Many more examples are there.

Comment: @Vikas we are guilty of eating plants too. Not all but I hope you get answer to some of your questions in the following post https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals

Comment: then why does shiva carry trishula? for killing insects?  no, for killing and eating fish. duh. god gave fish for man from time immemorial, but he resorted to non-Narayan habits

Answer (score 9):

Almost every scripture prohibit the consumption of beef(cow meat).

## Vedas

> Atharvaveda 10:1:29. The slaughter of an innocent, O Krityā, is an awful deed. **Slay not cow**, horse, or man of ours. In whatsoever place thou art concealed we rouse thee up there- from: become thou lighter than a leaf.

> Yajurveda 13:43. Unwasting Drop, red, eager, pressing forward, Agni I worship with repeated homage. Forming thyself with joints in proper order, **harm not the Cow,** Aditi widely ruling!

> Yajurveda 30:18. For the Dice-king a gambler; for the die Krita one who contemplates his adversary's ill luck, for the Tretâ a gamble-manager; for the Dvâpara a chief manager; for Askanda one who will not leave the gambling-hall; for Mrityu one who approaches cows; **for Antaka a Cow-killer; for Hunger one who goes begging to a man who is cutting up a cow;** for Misdeed a leader of the Charakas; for Misery a robber;

> Atharva-veda 12.4.38. Whoever looking on the Cow as fruitless, cooks her flesh at home, Brihaspati compels his sons and children of his sons to beg.

> Satapatha Brahmana 3.1.2.21
> [image]

## Purana

> Agni Purana 14:95
> [image]

> Agni Puran 227.32
> [image]

> Padma Puran 1.76.17
> [image]

> Linga Purana 66:52
> [image]

> Padma Puran 1.48.18b-19a
> [image]

> Vishnu Puran 2.6.8. He who causes absorption, plunders a town, **kills a cow** or strangles a man, goes to the Rodha hell.

> Agni Puran 227.40 A king should sentence death to those who kill a cow.

> Garuda Purana 105:12-13
> [image]

## Mahabharat

> Shanti Prava 262:47
> [image]

> Anushasan Parva LXXIV:- He, who, without being checked by the restraints of the scriptures, **sells a cow, or kills one, or eats the flesh of a cow, or they, who, for the sake of wealth, suffer a person to kill kine,--all these, viz., he that kills, he that eats, and he that permits the slaughter,--rot in hell for as many years as there are hairs on the body of the cow so slain.**

> Anushasan Parva CLVII:-All of them are mindful of sacrifices. All of them have Truth for their vow, and for these reasons all of them are regarded as equal to great Rishis. The goddess of Prosperity sports among them, and they, in their turn, support her with reverence. They never indulge in acts of fruitless congress with their wives, and **they never eat** the flesh of such animals as have not been killed in sacrifices.

## Ramayana

> "A regicide, a Brahman-cide, a cow-slayer, a thief, an inveterate killer, an atheist, and an younger brother who marries before his elder, all of them will go to hell. [4-17-36]

Well there are plenty of verses prohibiting slaughter of animals but you asked for cows especially so I focused on verses that mention cow slaughter specially.

Answer (score 6):

According to Hindu dharma it is allowed to kill some animal species, but only if it is done in accordance with the strict regulations of the scriptures, as in the sacrifices, as indicated in Manu-smriti and other scriptures.
However cows is explicitly forbidden to kill! There are explicit statements in the scriptures about it:

> ācāryaṃ ca pravaktāraṃ pitaraṃ mātaraṃ gurum /
>
> **na hiṃsyād** brāhmaṇān gāś ca sarvāṃś caiva tapasvinaḥ
>
> Let him **never offend (or injure)** the teacher who initiated him,
> nor him who explained the Veda, nor his father and mother, nor (any
> other) Guru, nor **cows**, nor Brahmanas, nor any men performing
> austerities. (Manu smriti 4.162)

In the above quotation from the Manu-smriti expression *na hiṃsyād* is translated as "never offend" or "never injure". So this verse is an evidence from the scriptures that killing of cows is not allowed!

There is a prayer in the Vishnu Purana 1.19.65:

> namo brahmaṇya-devāya go-brāhmaṇa-hitāya ca
>
> My Lord Krishna, You are the well-wisher of the cows and the Brahmanas.

In this verse cows and Brahmanas stand out as especially favored by the Lord, and thus they are especially sacred. Compare this with the above Manu-smriti verse where it is said that some people (Guru, father and mother, teacher who explained the Veda, Brahmanas), and cows should never be killed, and that is because of their special holiness.

It is said in the Bhagavad gita 18.44:

> kṛṣi-**go-rakṣya**-vāṇijyaḿ
>
> vaiśya-karma svabhāva-jam
>
> Farming, cow protection and business are the natural work for the
> vaiśyas.

In this verse phrase *go-rakṣya* was used, which means "cow protection". As we can see from this verse, in the varnashrama dharma cow protection is one of the primary activities. We are not supposed to kill those who we should protect! Right?

It is said in the Srimad Bhagavatam (Bhagavata Purana) 8.19.43 that in time of danger one should be engaged in *go-brāhmaṇa-arthe* "protecting cows and brahminical culture" (paraphrased).

In the Bhagavatam cows and Brahmanas again stand out in the canto 10, chapter 24 "Worshiping Govardhana Hill" where Lord Krishna encourages his father to perform a sacrifice:

http://vedabase.com/sb/10/24/en

> SB 10.24.25: Therefore may **a sacrifice for the pleasure of the cows,
> the brāhmaṇas and Govardhana Hill** begin! With all the paraphernalia
> collected for worshiping Indra, let this sacrifice be performed
> instead. ...
> ...
>
> ...
>
> SB 10.24.29: After everyone has eaten to his satisfaction, you should
> all dress and decorate yourselves handsomely, smear your bodies with
> sandalwood paste **and then circumambulate the cows, the brāhmaṇas, the
> sacrificial fires and Govardhana Hill**.
>
> SB 10.24.30: This is My idea, O father, and you may carry it out if it
> appeals to you. **Such a sacrifice will be very dear to the cows, the
> brāhmaṇas and Govardhana Hill, and also to Me.**

In the above verses we see that the Vedic sacrifice should be done for the pleasure of the Lord Krishna, cows, Govardhana Hill, and Brahmanas!
All of them must be that much especially sacred then.

There are many such verses in the scriptures that speak of a particular sanctity of cows and Brahmanas.

Comment: How would you interpret this chapter of the Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda then? http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2661.htm

Comment: Besides what is said in the texts, OP asks: *Are there any specific **logical or better arguments** or textual facts which suggest that eating beef is explicitly forbidden in Hinduism and **why** except the idea of worshiping cows?* ... he wants to know "why" apart from the "what". I think your answer addressed the what part.

Answer (score 5):

All Dharmic traditions without exception both Astik (believers in vedas) and Nastik (those who reject Vedas ... Buddhists, Jains etc) ***revere*** Cows (GoMata).

Meat eating though not recommended is allowed by many traditions, but Cow meat is forbidden and violations are punished.

Atharva Veda says:

> 1. Anago hatya vai bheema kritye.  Maa no gaamashvam purusham vadheeh. (Atharva Veda 10.1.29)

***It is definitely a great sin to kill innocents.  Do not kill our cows, horses and people.***

In Agamas there is specific rituals that need to be performed to GoMata (Cow). The milk of those cows as tremendous healing power including cancer.

Answer (score 4):

Cow is not worshipped as per canonical scriptures, in some Godly sense. If somebody worships his mother, it does not mean she is God/creator/Divine being, it only means that he gives her as much respect as the divine.

Some pantheistic sect of hinduism may even worship cow too in obscure literal sense, just as they worship tree deity etc. But uniformly across all the sects, the common thread is something like below:

**Cow is actually given respect as cultural symbol. Even in Arya samaj sect, which only worships one God and does not worship idols and does not believe in Avataras; that sect also revers Cow, they also explicitly treat her as cultural symbol of Vedic Hinduism.**

Just like saluting the indian flag, does not mean you are saluting that piece of cloth(of which flag is made). Saluting the flag means you are respecting the national symbol , which represents the nation and its ideal.
If somebody puts the national flag under his shoes, then people may react negatively to it. In the same sense, people are also attached to the cultural symbol. 
There is no scientific "logic" in why that particular piece of cloth should be treated as worthy of salute, or  no scientific "logic" why only that particular combination of color only should be treated as national symbol and no other particular combination. The only thing which matters is that once it was decided that tricolor will be our symbol/flag, then over a period our emotions and respect have got attached to that symbol. In the same way, the cultural symbols have history of respect of thousands of years.

---

Even sankhya followers, who are atheistic; they also give respect to cow and do not eat beef. So when they altogether do not beleive in God, so there is no question of worshipping anybody. So there is no question of worshipping cow. But still cultural symbol of reverence of cow is there in dharmic atheistic philosophies too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in knowing the scientific/social reasons for not eating beef, you could watch what Sadhguru says about it.

Having grown up raising cows and watching how they show emotions, especially with my parents who were very fond of the cows, Sadhguru's words make a lot of sense to me.

Here is an authentic video published by his channel:

[Is There A Basis For The Beef Ban? - Barkha Dutt with Sadhguru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E57nVL18akA)

And here is the text transcript:

[Basis for beef ban](https://isha.sadhguru.org/us/en/wisdom/video/basis-for-beef-ban)

And here is an excerpt from the same:

> ... So every life is happening the way it is happening because of a
>   certain dimension of information or in modern terminology, let’s call
>   it software. There is a certain software, which is an arrangement of
>   information.
>
> Now, the idea is to eat as simple a software as possible. If you eat
>   that kind of life, which is a very simple software, your ability to
>   override that software and make it entirely a part of you is very
>   good. As that software gets complex, more and more complex, your
>   ability to integrate it goes down. So, especially if it’s a creature
>   which has some sense of thought and emotion, then you should not eat it.
>   This is the understanding. An animal, which has any emotion, displays
>   certain emotions… especially if it displays emotion which is near to human 
>   emotion, you should not eat it because it will not integrate itself.
>   That animal nature will start manifesting itself.

Comment: 'An animal, which has any emotion, displays certain emotions…you should not eat it because it will not integrate itself' - by this primitive logic, lions should stop chasing deer and start eating grass that is available all year round. Early humans used to be hunter-gatherers until they discovered agriculture.

Comment: Sadhguru is talking about the 'software' of human beings, not lions or other animals in general.  We need to keep that in mind while trying to understand what he means.

Comment: I had done survey on Cow slaughter and eating beef. But this forum insists on Scriptures to prove. Hence I regret my inability to present my views.

Answer (score 2):

**shatapAtha brahmaNa Kanda III, adhyaya 1, brahmana 2** prohibits bull/cow slaughter for beef with reasons:

> *21. He (the Adhvaryu) then makes him enter the hall. **Let him not eat of either the cow or the ox; for the cow and the ox doubtless support everything here on earth**. The gods spake, 'Verily, the cow and the ox support everything here: come, let us bestow on the cow and the ox whatever vigour belongs to other species!' Accordingly they bestowed on the cow and the ox whatever vigour belonged to other species (of animals); and therefore the cow and the ox eat most. **Hence, were one to eat of an ox or a cow, there would be, as it were, an eating of everything, or, as it were, a going on to the end (or, to destruction). Such a one indeed would be likely to be born (again) as a strange being, (as one of whom there is) evil report, such as 'he has expelled an embryo from a woman,' 'he has committed a sin;' let him therefore not eat of the cow and the ox**.*

Answer (score 0):

Hindu taboo of eating beef is a cultural and got itself associated with the religion. None of the scriptures impose the restriction. It is a self-imposed ban by Hindus. [This](http://kalchiron.blogspot.com/2012/01/seven-prohibitions-self-imposed-by.html) blog post talks about it along with other self-imposed taboos by Hindus. 
An excerpt from that blog post:

> ..historicity of culture and evolution of certain traditions which
>   sometimes are misconstrued as "roots". The ultra veneration of cow is
>   one of them. There are many other instances. The fact that fanatic
>   veneration of cow led to other 6 famous "restrictions" on an Indic
>   mind ...
>
> The famous 7 restrictions (Sapta-Bandi) are 
>   ...
>
> 6 . Cow veneration - killing of cow and consumption of beef are "Mahaapaatakas" without any prayaschitta.  ...

The myth I've heard is that it was done since cattle population was declining steeply and they needed some measure to stop it and hence adopted such a stance. Some also blame the Muslim invaders for indiscriminately killing cattle which made the Hindus adopt such a stance. I don't have sources for these as there are word of mouth folk-lore.

While the scriptures do not impose ban on beef consumption, it does not also endorse eating beef. The Rig veda translation of Griffith & many others were mistranslated to mean that Vedic Hindus consumed beef. [This](http://sanatansinhnaad.blogspot.in/2013/06/misquoted-verses-of-hindu-scriptures.html) blog post talks about the mistranslations regarding Vedic Hindus eating beef.

Killing a cow causes as much himsa and bad karma as killing any other animal.

Comment: Since you mentioned himsa and negative karma towards killing any animal, does it promote vegetarianism?

Comment: Can you add a short summary/excerpt from the links you provided in order to indicate the focus behind what you want to convey?

Comment: Dharma is contextual. One rule does not apply to everyone. If you are a practicing Brahmana or involved in spiritual activity, killing/consuming meat would cause bad karma. If you are warrior fighting a war or a laborer toiling hard lifting heavy weights, it'd require eating meat & hence wouldn't cause bad karma as it's part of doing one's duty. Some complains that Hinduism itself is Brahminical & forces vegetarianism on everyone is a wrong assertion.

Comment: Added excerpt for the first link. For the 2nd there is a lots. You could search the page for 'beef' and you'd get to it.

Comment: @RBK - None of the scriptures impose the restriction - Really?

Comment: Eating meat is tamsic in nature. Eating meat for some special reason is understandable but it should be avoided.

Comment: @AksharRoop, yes. No specific restriction on beef but on all meat. See another question regarding eating non-veg food. It applies to every animal, not only cow.

Comment: All Dharmic traditions/religions not just Hinduism at their root agree on Cows being "sacred" and explicitly forbid killing of Cows

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of agenda and propaganda going on in this whole Hinduism Stackexchange site in general with some particular people being very biased and want to steer the discussions in a certain political direction that suits the Marxist missionary ideology.

I'll debunk some of their claims here. In general, meat has been mentioned several places in the ancient texts. But that does not mean Beef or specifically Cow meat. The Beef that India exports mostly is Buffalo meat, not Cow meat.

There is a mischievous question in another link. They come up with these texts:

**Manusmriti (5.30) :**

> It is not sinful to eat meat of eatable animals, for God has created
> both the eaters and the eatables.

Wrong translation. The Correct [translation](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm) is:

> 28. The Lord of creatures (Pragapati) created this whole (world to be) the sustenance of the vital spirit; both the immovable and the movable
>     (creation is) the food of the vital spirit.
> 29. What is destitute of motion is the food of those endowed with locomotion; (animals) without fangs (are the food) of those with
>     fangs, those without hands of those who possess hands, and the timid
>     of the bold.
> 30. The eater who daily even devours those destined to be his food, commits no sin; for the creator himself created both the eaters and
>     those who are to be eaten (for those special purposes).
> 31. 'The consumption of meat (is befitting) for sacrifices,' that is declared to be a rule made by the gods; but to persist (in using it)
>     **on other (occasions) is said to be a proceeding worthy of Rakshasas.**

So, it is clear that this is not about cow meat or even meat in general. It is for only sacrificial occasions.

**Rigveda (10/85/13) :**

> On the occasion of a girls marriage oxen and cows are slaughtered.

This is wrong translation. The shloka here does not say anything about cow slaughter at all. The actual [translation](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc839474.html) is:

> सू॒र्याया॑ वह॒तुः प्रागा॑त्सवि॒ता यम॒वासृ॑जत् । अ॒घासु॑ हन्यन्ते॒ गावोऽर्जु॑न्यो॒: पर्यु॑ह्यते ॥
>
> oxen are **whipped along** inthe Magha (constellations); she is borne (to
> her husband's house) in the Arjunī (constellations).”Sūrya's bridal procession which Savitā despatched has advanced; the

The previous and the next shlokas clearly mention about the Oxen driven chariots.

**Rigveda (6/17/1) :**

> Indra used to eat the meat of cow, calf, horse and buffalo.

Again, totally wrong. The correct [translation](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc833869.html) is as follows:

> पिबा॒ सोम॑म॒भि यमु॑ग्र॒ तर्द॑ ऊ॒र्वं गव्यं॒ महि॑ गृणा॒न इ॑न्द्र । वि
> यो धृ॑ष्णो॒ वधि॑षो वज्रहस्त॒ विश्वा॑ वृ॒त्रम॑मि॒त्रिया॒ शवो॑भिः ॥
>
> Fierce Indra, glorified by us, drink of the Soma, (animated) by which
> you have discovered the vast herd of cattle (stolen by Paṇis), and,
> overcomer of enemies, wielder of the thunderbolt, **you have slain, by**
> **your strength all opposing foes**.

**Vashishta Dharmasutra (11/34)** says:

> If a Brahmin refuses to eat the meat offered to him on the occasion
> of, 'Shraaddha' he goes to hell.

Wrong again. The actual [translation](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vasistha-dharmasutra/d/doc116373.html) is:

> But an **ascetic** who, **invited to dine at a sacrifice** of the manes or of
> the gods, rejects meat, shall go to hell for as many years as the
> slaughtered beast has hairs.

This is not about beef or even brahmin. This is an "Ascetic" - someone who is Invited to the offerings, **not the priest**. And it only says meat which is usually the case and nothing about cow meat. This text also clearly distinguishes between an Ascetic and a Brahmin.

So, we can conclude that there is **ZERO mention of cow meat eating in the ancient Hindu texts**. Meat is usually eaten during the offerings and sacrifices which is still the case in the Hindu society. Even regular Hindu meat eaters eat it only once a week. Not like in the west or in the abrahamic faiths.

Answer (score -2):

People's attitudes change with time. One can see this change in Hindu scriptures also. The earliest scriptures talk explicitly of meat eating **even eating beef**.

Chandogya Upanishad says that some spiritual aspirant takes a vow to not eat fish and meat for a year or to permanently stop eating non-veg food. The exact shloka is:

> He who thus knows this Yajnayajniya Saman, woven in the limbs of the
> body, is endowed with all the limbs, and is not crippled in any limb;
> he reaches the full length of life, lives gloriously, becomes great
> with offspring and cattle and great also with fame. His holy vow is
> that he should not eat fish and meat for a year, or rather, he should
> not eat fish and meat at all.

Chandogya Upanishad 2.19.2

Brhadaranyaka Upanishad says,

> ' He who wishes," May a son be born to me, who will be required
> scholar, attend assemblies, speak words that one likes to hear, be
> versed in all the Vedas, and attain full longevity", should have rice
> cooked with meat - that of a young and mature bull - and with his wife
> eat it mixed with ghee. Then they will be able to produce such a son.'
> That would imply that ancient Hindus used to eat meat.

Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 6.4.18

There is also a passage that **directly praises offering of Beef at Sraddhas**:

> Bhishma said, ' Listen to me, O Yudhisthira, what those havis are
> which persons conversant with the ritual of the Sraddha regard as
> suitable in view of the Sraddha and what the fruits are that attach to
> each. With sesame seeds and rice and barley and Masha and water and
> roots and fruits, if given at Sraddhas, the Pitris, O king, remain
> gratified for the period of a month. ......**With beef presented at the
> Sraddha,** their gratification, it is said, lasts for a full year.

Mahabharata, Anusasana Parva, Section LXXXVIII

Later scriptures condemn animal sacrifice. For example, Bhishma said in Mahabharata,

> "Beholding the mangled body of a bull, and hearing the exceedingly
> painful groans of the kine in a cow-slaying sacrifice, and observing
> the cruel Brahmanas that gathered there for assisting at the
> ceremonies, that king uttered these words, ‘Prosperity to all the kine
> in the world.’ When the slaughter had commenced, these words
> expressive of a blessing (to these helpless animals) were pronounced.
> And the monarch further said, ‘Only those that are transgressors of
> defined limits, that are destitute of intelligence, that are atheists
> and sceptics, and that desire the acquisition of celebrity through
> sacrifices and religious rites speak highly of slaughter of animals in
> sacrifices.’"

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXV

Another passage in Mahabharata says,

> 'Cast thy eyes, O Jajali, on those bullocks yoked to the plough. Kine
> are called in the Srutis the Unslayable. That man perpetrates a great
> sin who slays a bull or a cow. In days of yore, many Rishis with
> restrained sense addressed Nahusha, saying, " Thou hast, O King, slain
> **a cow which is declared in the scriptures to be like unto one's
> mother.** Thou hast also slain a bull, which is declared to be like unto
> the Creator himself. Thou hast perpetrated an evil act, O Nahusha, and
> we have been exceedingly pained by it."'

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXII

The Sanskrit word for cow is go. The word go stands both for cow and rays of the sun.

> **Kine – rays of the sun**
>
> In respect of the prosperity and the growth that kine confer, in the
> matter also of the protection that kine grant unto all creatures of
> the earth, kine are equal to the very rays of the sun that fall on the
> earth. The word that signifies the cow stands also for the rays of the
> sun. The giver of a cow becomes the progenitor of a very large race
> that extends over a large part of the earth. Hence, he that gives a
> cow shines like a second sun in resplendence.

Mahabharata, Anusasana Parva, Section LXXI

In Hinduism light is usually a metaphor for spiritual illumination. Thus a cow is a symbol of the spiritual light within us. Just as the sun supports entire life on Earth similarly the spiritual light within gives us consciousness,i.e., makes conscious life possible. It is in this sense that a cow is a holy animal. Not killing a cow simply means not doing any immoral act that dims that spiritual light.

Some scholars think the change in attitude towards eating beef (and meat) is due to the influence of Buddhism and Jainsim.

Comment: If cow represents sun rays, why is it slaughtered on the arrival of an important guest? The Sanskrit word 'goghna' [means](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=goghna&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) 'guest' / 'one for whom a cow is killed'.

Comment: I can only guess at the answer. It is possible that Hindus initially used to interpret not killing a cow in a spiritual sense. This explains why Mahabharata mentions a King Rantideva killing lots of cows to feed the guests.Later on Hindus began to take 'not killing a cow' literally and the spiritual view was either downplayed or even forgotten.

Comment: @sv. In brahmanams, in samhitas go does mean sun. Samhitas symbolize rituals unlike brahmanams.

Comment: It's ray of sun or that of knowledge? i think it's JyAna rasmi? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: @Rickross Sri K.M.Ganguli translates the text as ray of sun.