# Is there any mention of consuming egg in any sastra or puran?

Tags: scripture, puranas, food, non-vegetarian

Is there  any mention of consuming egg in any sastra or puran?

I mean **details** vidhi about

1. when to consume when to avoid.
2. what are the merits or demerits .
3. food value
4. how to consume etc etc

if yes then please provide the details

Comment: Related [What are Tamasic, Rajasic and Sattvic foods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2659/16823)

Answer (score 7):

[Atharvaveda 8.6.23](https://sites.google.com/a/vedicgranth.org/www/misconceptions-on-vedas/misconception-3---violence-against-animals-meet-eating-etc/non-violence-to-animals) condemns the consumption of eggs.

It states

> Ya aamam maansamadanti paurusheyam cha ye kravih 
> Garbhaan khaadanti keshavaastaanito naashayaamasi
>
> We ought to destroy those who eat cooked as well as uncooked meat, meat involving destruction of males and females, foetus and eggs.

Answer (score 2):

**Both fertilized & unfertilized eggs are Non-Veg**.

Veg/Non-Veg categorization is based on moral reasons:

1. **Fertilized egg**: This is egg which contains unborn baby and hence this is **Non-Veg**
2. **Unfertilized egg**: This is also Non-Veg because for getting unfertilized eggs, you will have to separate Hen from Rooster. Separating wife (Hen) from Husband (Rooster) is immoral and hence unfertilized egg is also **Non-Veg**.
   mahAbhArata Adi parva ch. CXVIII also considers this a sinful act as deer censures/curses pAndu for denying sexual relation between male & female animal:

> ***The sexual intercourse is agreeable to every creature and productive of good to all**.
> **But that effort of mine
> hath been rendered futile by thee**.*

Atharvaveda 8.6.23 also condemns the consumption of eggs as mentioned already

As per [mahAbhArata shAntiparva CCLXXXII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b109.htm) , chicken/chicken-products are forbidden :

> *From the blood of Vritra, O son of Pritha, were born **high-crested cocks**. For this reason, **those fowls are unclean (as food)** for the
> regenerate classes, and those ascetics that have undergone the rite of
> initiation.*