# Why should we be vegetarian?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

Many people ask me 'why are you a vegetarian?', but I don't have a perfect answer for them.

**I want a perfect answer on why should we be vegetarian**

Comment: there are more possible answers  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/349/why-are-some-food-items-advised-against-by-the-vedas and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/what-are-tamasic-rajasic-and-sattvic-foods since gunas are very important and are constituent tattwas of our body.

Answer (score -1):

Just to propagate the hindu theory of non violence, which I guess every religion propagate in their own way.this is Hindu way. Right or wrong should be individuals discretion.

Comment: This looks like opinion. You should cite some sources. Visit [help] for more information.