# How can Lord rama consume meat without sacrificing it to the dieties first?

Tags: ramayana, rama, food

All scriptures unanimously agree that eating meat without sacrifice is a sin, then why is there no mention of Lord rama sacrificing animals, there are no verses which directly state that he ate meat but are all indirect speculation, how can one be sure that he really did eat meat?

Comment: As a kshatriya he is entitled to take non vegetarian food. During Vanavas  it is a compulsion as there is less supply of fresh vegetables in the forest.

Comment: I think you're refuting the claims , more or less that is already discussed at [Was Lord Rama a non-vegetarian?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2002/277)