# Growing animals and killing for food is not a sin?

Tags: gods, bhagavad-gita, belief, non-vegetarian, non-hindu

I have heard a lot about the killing of animals as a sin. Some say it's a food cycle that can be justified. But why one should grow to kill that in unconditional ways?

A normal chicken growth takes 6months time, but to feed people's stomachs they are growing it in a span of 1 or 2 months time and killing it.

Is this not a sin irrespective of every religion?

What does Bhagwadgeetha say on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can we eat 'living' plants but not 'living' animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals)

Comment: @Vivikta - not really, I have read all that answers and posted my question. This is w.r.to out of the box question from just non-veg and food lifecycle and the greediness of people.

Comment: Okay, but we cannot answer from Quran and Bible, etc. That's not within HSE's scope. You should strike those two.