# Eating restrictions in Hinduism

Tags: non-vegetarian, food

According to the Wikipedia page on [Hindu diet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_in_Hinduism), an excerpt from the Atharva Veda (the chronologically last one of the four) says that

> Those who eat flesh uncooked, and those who eat the bleeding flesh of
>   men, Feeders on babes unborn, long-haired, far from this place we
>   banish these.

My question is if the religious Hindu texts haven't explicitly prescribed any particular eating preferences, why is this act of eating non-conventional meat (e.g. beef or pork) frowned upon by some of the conservatives?

I've had the opinion that Hinduism is a religion of universal acceptance and the eating habits of a person has got nothing to do with the Hindu religion.

Is this true or does Hinduism have some specific culinary instructions for its followers?

Comment: My question is similar but not exactly identical. The difference is that I want to know about specific classes of forbidden meat, e.g. beef or pork, in contrast to the more general question of about being a veg/non-veg. Furthermore, I want to clarify whether ancient Hinduism had anything to say about eating habits or not because my feeling is that the eating preferences (which have been imbibed in the culture over the years) are often misunderstood as religious restrictions.

Comment: Foods which increase Rajas & Tamas gunas are usually advised against. No specific types of meat is encouraged over another. All meat leads to Rajas.
Maybe similar to http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/67/eating-beef-as-a-hindu

Comment: I think your question already has an answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/72/81).