# Meat-eating and Hinduism

Tags: vedas

According to the overall Hindu scriptural tradition, does meat-eating impede spiritual progress? I know that the classical Vaishnava traditions seem to prohibit it.  How about the other sects and paths within the grand Hindu Faith? Do the Vedas comment on this aspect?

Comment: Also See [Eating Beef as a Hindu](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/67/3500) and [Should a Brahmin be vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8206/3500)